# IOS: remove imageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have this code:

```
for(Contact *contact in myArray){
        if(...){
            UIImageView *fix = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
            [self.view addSubview:fix];
            [fix setFrame:[contact square]];
            return;
        }
    }
```

in this code I add an imageView on self.view but in my app i call this "for" many times and finally I have my self.view with 4 or 5 imageView "fix".
What's the way to remove all these imageView from my self.view?

Comment: the return-statement will return the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to remove instances of UIImageView, you can try something like this:

```
for (UIView *v in self.view.subviews) {
    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        [v removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As **vikingosegundo** wrote in the comments, you can do this instad.

If you add each imageview to an array, you can remove them from the view later on like this:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for Contact *contact in myArray){
    if(...){
        UIImageView *fix = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        [self.view addSubview:fix];
        [fix setFrame:[contact square]];
        [images addObject:fix]; // Add the image to the array.
        return;
    }
}
```

The later on, remove them from the view:

```
for (UIImageView *v in images) {
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: in this way it remove all my imageView, but I should remove only those that I add in my "for"; can I use an NSMutableArray?

Comment: You can not add the UIImageViews to an array directly, and then remove them from self.view by referencing them from the array. You need a reference to each UIImageView (ie. a tag). I updated my answer, I hope that works for you.

Comment: This don't put Numbers in the array, but just simply the UIImageViews `[images addObject:fix];`

Comment: `for (UIView *v in images){[v removeFromSuperview];}`

Comment: also the return-statement is most likely not what you want here. this would return the whole method.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: No, that does not work. You have to use a reference to the UIImageViews that is in `self.view.subviews`.

Comment: @matsr — I am referencing the view, by keeping its pointer, standard OOP-technique.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: I tried that before I tried what I wrote in my answer, in which it did not remove the image. Please explain what made it work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did a mistake. I used the NSMutableArray as a property, and forgot to alloc/init it before adding the UIImageViews to it. My bad! I updated my answer.

Comment: ehmm, did you see, that I also posted an answer, and that your edited answer now reads like a copy of it?

Comment: Well, that was the code I wrote when I tested this at first, except from the first line that creates the array.

Answer (score 1):

Just call removeFromSuperview for every subView. Something like:

```
for(UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];

for Contact *contact in myArray){
    if(...){
        UIImageView *fix = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
        [self.view addSubview:fix];
        [fix setFrame:[contact square]];
        [images  addObject:fix];
    }
}


for (UIView *v in images){
    [v removeFromSuperview];
}
```

---

Another approach

```
for(UIView *v in self.view.subviews)
    if([v isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        [v removeFromSuperview];
```

---

I put an [example](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/HideImages/HideImages) together.